# ASP .NET Core 3.1 API redirects to login page in prod environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created an ASP .NET Core 3.1 website which uses MVC (at least to the best of my understanding). Apart from the login page I use cookie auth to restrict access. One of the controllers has got an action decorated with the `[HttpPost]` and `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes.
When running the website on my computer everything works just fine, but when I deploy it to my prod server (Server 2016 + IIS) and post to the action using Postman I get redirected to the login page and the HTML of the login page is returned.
The rest of the website, login etc works just fine. It's only the API I'm having problems with.

I also tried creating a brand new controller using the template from Visual Studio, but the result is the same.
Removing the `[Authorize]` attribute from the controller also did not change the situation.

Would anybody know why that might be?
Let me know if there is any information missing you might need.

My controller (simplified)

```
[Authorize]
public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
...
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery] string searchTerms, [FromQuery] bool updateDb)
    {
        ...
        return View(vm);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public string PostAction([FromBody] object postBody)
    {
        //Process data (JSON)
        return "SomeProcessedDataString";
    }
...
}
```

Cookie auth stuff in `startup.cs`

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication("myCookieScheme")
                .AddCookie("myCookieScheme", (CookieAuthenticationOptions config) =>
                {
                    config.Cookie.Name = "myLoginCookie";
                    config.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            ...

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an `services.AddAuthorization(...)` in your `startup.cs` and how is that setup?

Comment: Just had a look. I don't have AddAuthorization anywhere in my code, just `AddAuthentication`, `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization`.
I just tried adding `services.AddAuthorization()` (note default constructor) and it's still the same.

Comment: Have you set up the endpoint routing?

Comment: @PlamenYordanov I added the `app.UseEndpoints` section to my original question. I am using the default route that came with the MVC template.
At some point I also decorated my ApplicationController with the `[ApiController]` and `[Route("[Controller]"` attributes and the actions itself with a `[Route]` attribute itself, but that also didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem myself.
Due to file system permission settings on the prod server the POST action was erroring out, which then caused ASP.NET core to redirect to the login page.
Hope this helps somebody else in the future.